# Image not found in the Bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have the next issues, xcode cannot find one image but there are in the bundle  and in the `InterfaceBuilder` detect the image but when I'm running the application don't run because dont finde them this happen because I reorganize all te images in other folders but when i put the image again in the folder first created this ok but in the folder I want to store the image don't found it.

How can I fix that?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XCode click on your Target, then select Build Phases, then look at Copy Bundle Resources and check you file is there and add it if not.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the reference to the image in your xcode project. Move it to where ever you want to keep it. Then in xcode again, add the image to your project.